# How to retry a statement on error?

Tags: r, error-handling

How can I simply tell R to retry a statement a few times if it errors? E.g. I was hoping to do something like:

```
tryCatch(dbGetQuery(...),           # Query database
    error = function(e) {
        if (is.locking.error(e))    # If database is momentarily locked
            retry(times = 3)        # retry dbGetQuery(...) 3 more times
        else {
            # Handle other errors
        }
    }
)
```

Answer (score 60, accepted):

I usually put the `try` block in a loop, 
and exit the loop when it no longer fails or the maximum number of attempts is reached.

```
some_function_that_may_fail <- function() {
  if( runif(1) < .5 ) stop()
  return(1)
}

r <- NULL
attempt <- 1
while( is.null(r) && attempt <= 3 ) {
  attempt <- attempt + 1
  try(
    r <- some_function_that_may_fail()
  )
}
```

Comment: Should set attempt=0 at start.

Comment: @horaceT Why? With `attempt <- 1` at the onset, there will be at most 3 attempts, which seems to be the aim. You could replace `attempt <= 3` with `attempt <= num_of_attempts`.

Answer (score 18):

I wrote a quick function that allows you to easily retry an operating a configurable number of times, with a configurable wait between attempts:

```
library(futile.logger)
library(utils)

retry <- function(expr, isError=function(x) "try-error" %in% class(x), maxErrors=5, sleep=0) {
  attempts = 0
  retval = try(eval(expr))
  while (isError(retval)) {
    attempts = attempts + 1
    if (attempts >= maxErrors) {
      msg = sprintf("retry: too many retries [[%s]]", capture.output(str(retval)))
      flog.fatal(msg)
      stop(msg)
    } else {
      msg = sprintf("retry: error in attempt %i/%i [[%s]]", attempts, maxErrors, 
                    capture.output(str(retval)))
      flog.error(msg)
      warning(msg)
    }
    if (sleep > 0) Sys.sleep(sleep)
    retval = try(eval(expr))
  }
  return(retval)
}
```

So you can just write `val = retry(func_that_might_fail(param1, param2), maxErrors=10, sleep=2)` to retry calling that function with those parameters, give up after 10 errors, and sleep 2 seconds between attempts.

Also, you can redefine the meaning of what an error looks like by passing a different function as parameter `isError`, which by default will catch an error signaled with `stop`. This is useful if the function being called does something else on error, such as returning `FALSE` or `NULL`.

This is the alternative I've found so far that results in clearer, more readable code.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 15):

A solution without pre-assigning values and using `for` instead of `while`:

```
some_function_that_may_fail <- function(i) {
  if( runif(1) < .5 ) stop()
  return(i)
}

for(i in 1:10){
  try({
    r <- some_function_that_may_fail(i)
    break #break/exit the for-loop
  }, silent = FALSE)
}
```

`r` will be equal to the number of tries that were needed. If you dont want the output of the errors set `silent` to `TRUE`

Answer (score 5):

Here's a function to generate a custom condition to respond to

```
locked <- function(message="occurred", ...) {
    cond <- simpleCondition(message, ...)
    class(cond) <- c("locked", class(cond))
    cond
}
```

and a function implemented to allow (an infinite number of) restarts

```
f <- function() {
    cnt <- 0L
    repeat {
        again <- FALSE
        cnt <- cnt + 1L
        withRestarts({
            ## do work here, and if needed...
            signalCondition(locked())
        }, retry=function() {
            again <<- TRUE
        })
        if (!again) break
    }
    cnt
}
```

and the use of `withCallingHandlers` (to keep the context where the condition was signaled active unlike `tryCatch`) to handle the `locked` condition

```
withCallingHandlers({
    n_tries <- 0L
    f()
}, locked=function(e) {
    n_tries <<- n_tries + 1L
    if (n_retries < 3)
        invokeRestart("retry")
})
```

Answer (score 5):

I have put together the code and make it package: [retry](https://github.com/randy3k/retry)

```
f <- function(x) {
    if (runif(1) < 0.9) {
        stop("random error")
    }
    x + 1
}

# keep retring when there is a random error
retry::retry(f(1), when = "random error")
#> [1] 2
# keep retring until a requirement is satisified.
retry::retry(f(1), until = function(val, cnd) val == 2)
#> [1] 2
# or using one sided formula
retry::retry(f(1), until = ~ . == 2, max_tries = 10)
#> [1] 2
```

Comment: Is it possible to incorporate a timeout for each attempt? For example, I have a function that should not take longer than 10 seconds to run. If it does take longer, I want this attempt to timeout, and then I want retry to try again. It looks like the timeout parameter within retry is limited to the global runtime, not each attempt.

Answer (score 2):

I like setting my object as an error from the start, also sometimes useful to add some sleep time if you're having connection problems:

```
res <- simpleError("Fake error to start")
counter <- 1
max_tries <- 10 
# Sys.sleep(2*counter)
while(inherits(res, "error") & counter < max_tries) { 
  res <- tryCatch({ your_fun(...) }, 
      error = function(e) e)
  counter <- counter + 1
}
```

Comment: this needs to be & not OR :: while(inherits(res, "error") & counter < max_tries) {