# How to pause R script when error

Tags: r, try-catch

I would like to use sys.sleep function when the request of an API I am using gives me an error back.
Like this one:

> Error in open.connection(con, "rb") : HTTP error 429.

Should I use trycatch?

```
data<- fromJSON("https://api.com")
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

You can use try catch

```
tryCatch(myfunc(), error=function(e) Sys.sleep(1))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It seems to work well, although it looks that it will just do Sys.sleep after 1 error, but after a 2nd error it won't do it again. So could I mix what you suggested with a while loop ? In order to say that "as long as there is an error, do Sys.sleep"

Comment: I think the following is what you are looking for.   Take a look at the retry function that is posted , it will do to retry an operating a configurable number of times, with a configurable wait between attempts https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20770497/how-to-retry-a-statement-on-error